# C++ indentifier "read" conflicts?

Tags: c++

Recently I'm working on my toy final c++ project, which will read content from a file at the begining and then process it.

Here's the simplified code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//using namespace std;
struct command{
    int a;
};
command read[1]; 
int main() {
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("123.txt");
    if (!fin){
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    char c;
    fin >> c;
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine with `Visual Studio 2019`. However, when I'm trying to use `devc++ 5.11 TDM-GCC 4.9.2`, a strange bug happens. I get a segmentation fault on line `fin>>c;`, with return code 3221225477.

With great effort, the easiest way to make this code works is changing the identifier `read` to names like `reading` or whatever. Besides, moving the line `command read[1];` into main function also helps.

My questions are:

- Is it a behavior related to the compiler? MSVC is fine but GCC 4.9.2 is a little bit old or ...?
- Does the identifier `read` conflict with something in my code? Why does it not a compile error but a segmentation fault?
- Why does moving the declaration of `read` into main function help?

Update:Thanks for tips and I removed `using namespace std`. I think it has something to do with `ifstream`, because just `std::cout<<"hello world";` works.
`-Wall -Wextra` provides no warnings.

Comment: What is `read` even doing there? Why do you have an array of one thing?

Comment: Tip: Get rid of `using namespace std` and embrace the `std::` prefix. It helps separate your code from the standard library.

Comment: It's possible this is a symbol conflict with the [`read()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) function. Are you compiling with `-Wall` to get warnings?

Comment: @tadman that's just the simpified code, in my project read is uesd to store some data, I locate my bug here and delete useless code. It's length is one because i'm tring to reduce the memory used (because of the segmentation fault).

Comment: Fair if this is just a demonstration of a minimal failure case. I do see people allocate arrays of size one in real code though and in most cases it's an anti-pattern, so just mentioning it here to be sure.

Comment: thx for your tips, i add  -Wall -Wextra ( get no warnings ) and modify code (remove using namespace) in the question but the bug is still there :( , and still can be fixed in the same way.@tadman

Comment: @Goodgame It's not necessarily a bug.  MSVC is Windows-only, where there isn't a `read()` function from the OS-supplied C runtime library.  [`read()` is a POSIX function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) and almost certainly usable in your GCC implementation from its entirely different C++ runtime.  Whether or not it's proper to put `read()` in the `std::` namespace is a good question itself that I haven't found a good answer for here and I'm not a C++ language-lawyer.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `std::ifstream fin; fin.open("123.txt");` to `std::ifstream fin("123.txt");`.

Answer (score 0):

GCC compiler is stricter than other compiler.

According to tadman's describe, we can guess there's `read` symbol in namespace std.

So you put it out of main,it's a conflict, you put in the main, it become a local symbol.

Comment: `read()` that @tadman referenced is a Linux system call and therefore not in std. Strictly speaking, the compiler is not C++ standard-compliant here - defining a non-standard global.

Comment: Thanks, I removed `using namespace std` but the bug still exits..

Comment: That's means there's another read in global namespace,not in std.@Good game

Answer (score 0):

There is very likely a collision happening between your `read` and another in the global namespace.  Not all compilers handle this situation the same way, but you can always avoid it if you are careful.

Visual Studio's Intellisense (or whatever alternative you prefer) can help you identify what symbol your `read` is colliding with.  To do that, scope or comment out your code, then start typing "`read`".  If there's another `read` in your scope, you'll likely see it and be able to get information about it.

This is one of the reasons I don't like `using namespace std;`.  It pollutes your global namespace with a bunch of stuff and increases your chance of collision with a standard library identifier.

Comment: It is the other way around: Visual Studio works correctly here, and g++ has the unexpected global `read()`.